# XCTest UI when using iOS Buttons

Tags: localization, xcuitest

I'm doing some UI testing which is working in EN (Development language). But not so when tested with other languages. For example, the Cancel button in a SearchBar can be tapped by

```
    app.buttons["Cancel"].tap()
```

But in Spanish "Cancel" is actually "Cancelar" so the test fails to find the button when ran in Spanish.

One way would be to look for buttons by index but this is dangerous because it could break if Apple moves the button to a different index.

```
app.buttons.element(boundBy: indexOfCancelButton).tap()
```

Is there an easier and more reliable way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set an `acceessibilityIdentifier` on the views you want to interact with in UI tests.

Accessibility identifiers are unlocalized and so will not change when you change the language of the device running the tests.

Accessibility identifiers are not visible to the end user in any way and are only used for UI tests.

```
// app code
let button: UIButton!
button.accessibilityIdentifier = "cancelButton"

// test code
let app = XCUIApplication()
let cancelButton = app.buttons["cancelButton"]
cancelButton.tap()
```

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear ... I need to be able to access built-in iOS buttons. Like the example I gave. When you bring up a searchBar you get a cancel button. This button is built into the SearchBar. I can't see a way to get access to it and set it's identifier property. For everything else, yes, you simply set the identifier property and that works perfectly.